# Язык для обучения хакингу

Tags: взлом

Подскажите, какие языки вы бы порекомендовали изучить для дальнейшего обучения хакерству?

Comment: А что Вы подразумеваете под хакерством?

Comment: я обладаю только основными языками сайтостроения.(html css php javascript jquery)
а под хакерством я даже не знаю что подразумеваю так как мало что о нем знаю а идея занятся хакерством ко мне пришла только в целях защиты  своих интернет проектов.

Comment: тогда Вам надо заняться скорее методами компьютерной безопасности, а приемы хакеров изучать как оружие врага. Но это все требует довольно серьезной подготовки и обширных знаний. Знаний нескольких языков, операционных систем, на которых развернут ресурс, криптографии (что требует хороших знаний математики) и т.д., и т.п. Так что, "учитесь, Антуан, учитесь".

Comment: подпишитесь на журнал Хакер, лишним не будет.

Comment: Плохой вопрос. Поясните в теме что такое "хакинг". Наверное имеете ввиду информационную безопасность?

Comment: на css и html хакать круче всего!!!

P.S. адресовано автору)

Comment: Palmervan, харе стебаться надо мной ).

Comment: Vladimir VG. В моем случае причина изучения хакинга да ( безопасность )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С++, SQL - запросы, а вообще-то для хакерства любой язык годится.) Но еще нужно знать хорошо TCP/IP, клиент-серверные технологии.

Касаясь языков программирования, то я бы предпочел С++ или С#. Полезно в этом деле знать Script.

Интересуйтесь криптографией, ) так как знаний одного языка будет мало.

Comment: На заметку - если собираетесь быть "хакером" - читните хоть википедию по этому вопросу что-бы Вы различали хакера и ламера...

Comment: AlexWindHope. Стать хакером в планах у меня не было . 
Я просто захотел стать этичным хакером в своих целях безопасности .

Comment: Ну я тоже не обладаю екстрасенсорными способностями, просто по опыту знаю что понятие "хакер" у многих ассоциируется с понятием хакера...<br>Вот на всякий случй и уточнил

Answer (score 6):

Ответ немного не по теме, скорее в общеобразоватльных целях.

Собственно, понятие "хакинг" не такое негативное, как привыкли многие воспринимать. Это не обязательно взлом, спам или еще какое-то западло. Суть хака вообще в использовании "недокументированных возможностей" либо документированных возможностей непредвиденным способом. Т.е. именно по сути, по философии хака, так сказать, вазочка для цветов из 1.5-литровой бутылки есть хак в той же степени, что и sql-инъекция. Грустно то, что хак как культура практически мертв - ребята из середины 90-х за людей не считали взломщиков, ломающих что-то ради бабла, именно когда бабло было единственной целью (примечателен случай парня, поломавшего банк и заказавшему девушке грузовик роз). Сейчас "хакеры" тусовка ммм... даже не знаю как их назвать, в общем, криворуких редисок, которые вешают блокировщики экрана, воруют аккаунты из вконтакта или аськи и продают по 10р/штука спамерам. А тут примечателен случай, когда я убил блокировщика по сети с помощью ArtMoney =)

Короче, я к чему. Эта штука полезна вообще во всех отношениях, но требует от человека очень многого - как минимум, соответствующего склада ума (это можно натренировать, но не с полного нуля), в случае с компами - огромного багажа знаний (программирование(не меньше 3 языков разных типов), сети, ОС, микросхемы, психология(!), матан, шифрование), а также большого количества свободного времени (многие взломы проходили по несколько месяцев). Если вы хотите защитить ваши проекты и не более того - читайте спц. литературу по компьютерной безопасности, сайтики типа xakep.ru и securitylab.ru, периодически проверяйте багтрекеры и своевременно обновляйте ПО - это защитит вас от 99.5% атак. Но не от спортивного интереса "трушного" хакера, ибо от дурака защиты нет)) А если правда хотите разорвать матрицу, изобретать, ломать стены и делать лазеры из дохлых DVD-приводов - хакером надо быть везде и всегда.

Прошу прощения за объем, просто во-первых, тема "родная", во-вторых, накопилась злость на криворуких редисок)

Comment: Мне понравилось.

Comment: мне статья очень понравилась.
блестящая,безупречная,добросовестно написанная.
спасибо что не оставили мой вопрос без внимания.
статья действительно  заслуживающая одобрения, похвалы,внимания.

Comment: Не со всем согласен, но "<b> от дурака защиты нет</b>" это истина ^^

Answer (score 1):

Мое мнение, что любой подойдет любой язык, потому что все они прекрасно работают через CGI. Но приоритет можно отдать сравнительно простым и распространенным: Python, PHP, Perl, либо более навороченным C# или даже C++, последний правда не очень часто используется в этом контексте. И в обязательном порядке SQL. Знание работы HTTP протокола - вещь также неотъемлемая.

Answer (score 0):

Хороший вопрос. Это типа, как если бы на форуме слесарей спросили: из какой марки стали лучше делать отмычки?

Comment: ))Все таки тематика моего вопроса может чуть чуть но все таки где то пересекаются с тематикой этого сайта . А задаю я его здесь так как я ни где больше не встречал такого приятного общества как на hashcode.ru. Respect всем кто сидит на hashcode

Comment: Вообще-то такие вопросы надо задавать шепотом. Не боитесь попасть под контроль ФСБ?

Comment: [OFFTOP]<small>Любите нас и будете любимы ^^</small>[/OFFTOP]

Comment: И вам не кашлять

Answer (score 0):

Боюсь стать хакером для вас уже наразумно. когда вы зарегистрировались на широкоизвестном сайте а там более засветились постом, это уже может быть достаточно для того чтоб вас найти :)

То что вы задаете этот вопрос говорит наталкивает на 2 мысли:
1) либо вы вообще в этом не разбираетесь и незнаете даже с чего начать (как исправить: учится учится учится учится)
2) либо вы слишком уверенный в своих силах человек и сделали необдуманый поступок. что для кулхацкера неприпустимо :) (будьте впредь осторожнее, на каждого умника найдется умник поумнее)

p.s. я б посоветовал начать, так сказать, с самого "конца" - с криптографии. рано или поздно вы к ней придете. но если же начать с нее то она будет вам указателем к технологиям, умениям которые нужно освоить и хорошо владеть.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще чтобы иметь полный и безотказный доступ (удобно для хакеров для написание вирусов и т.д.) нужно писать проги на ассемблере

Comment: ИМХО - глупости...

Comment: Доступ к чему? Писать вирусы - ассемблер. Все остальное вполне может без него обойтись (за весьма редким исключением). Хотя сам я асм очень люблю.

Answer (score 0):

Надо провести грань быть White Hat или Black Hat или Green Hat.
Отсюда и отталкиваться ,выше уже приведены языки С++ и C#.Все зависит от самого человека и его типа мышления(хакером просто так не становятся.)
Посмотри фильм "Хакеры 2:Операция взлом" вот там 2 хакера воюют =) Глядишь сайтики получше для тебя окажется, чем неделями архив пытаться взломать.